Not wearing Pants in MLB will lead to an automatic walk?
The MLB rules define the strike zone as follows:
"The official strike zone is the area over home plate from the midpoint between a batter's shoulders and the top of the uniform pants -- when the batter is in his stance and prepared to swing at a pitched ball -- and a point just below the kneecap. In order to get a strike call, part of the ball must cross over part of home plate while in the aforementioned area."
As the pants are part of the definition, would not wearing pants lead to a non existing strike zone and therefore an automatic walk?

This is actually an interesting question.  Not so much regarding the case of players not wearing pants (not sure if that would increase or decrease viewership!), but given that uniforms have changed over the decades, it is clear that this rule, or its interpretation, would have to change if uniforms changed significantly.  For example, if overalls or high-waisted uniforms with suspenders come into fashion, the top of the uniform pants would be substantially different than current uniforms. And let's hope low-rider uniforms never come into style... especially for fans sitting behind home plate.

As I've said before, sports are not computer programs where you blindly follow the rules as written. The intent of the rule is clear, and umpires will follow the intent.
Also note that any player not wearing pants in an MLB game will almost certainly be subject to discipline by the league for bringing the game into disrepute.

Between rule 3.03 and the implications that pants are expected by the strike zone rule, yeah.
